# fetch server data but can't use data.map, with array.map is not a function in next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I am working on a list page with next.js 13 to show a list of projects.

i tried to make it work in the server rendering.

app/team/page.tsx

```tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
export default async function useProjects() {
  const res = await fetch('/api/projects')
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

import useProjects from '@/hooks/use-projects';    
import { useRouter} from 'next/navigation';

const Team = () => {

  const  projects  = useProjects();
  console.log('projects ', projects);

  return (
    <SettingsLayout
      title="Projects"
      RightHeading={
        <>

        </>
      }
    >
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-3">
        {
          projects.map((project) => (
            <Link
              key={`project-card-${project.slug}`}
              href={`/${team?.slug}/${project.slug}`}
            >
              <div className="truncate whitespace-nowrap rounded-lg border border-neutral-800 bg-neutral-1000 p-8 text-neutral-100 transition hover:bg-neutral-900">
                {project.name}
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
      </div>
    </SettingsLayout>
  );
};

export default Team;
```

the server can fetch the projects data successfully. and the result is showed up to the console.log.

[image]

but the page doesn't show in the correct way.

[image]

**update**

I followed @Phil's method in the client rendering.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const fetchProjects = async () => {
   // simulated data
  const data = [{"id":"f0dc4b06-063a-4ed7-a712-463b418ae436","slug":"starter","name":"Starter","is_starter":true}];
  return data;
};


export default async function useProjects() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  // fetch projects on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    try{
      let data =  fetchProjects();
      console.log('get data ',data);  // outputs the fetched data

/*
get data   
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(1)
*/
      setProjects(data);
    }catch(error){
      setError(error)
    } 
    setLoading(false);

  }, []);
  return { projects, loading, error };
}
```

but in the another components

```
const Team = () => {

  const { projects, loading, error } =  useProjects();
  console.log('projects', projects);

  .... 

}
```

the error disappeared but console 's output is undefined. there is no projects data in the component.

If I don't use hook but put the code directly in the component.

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProjects = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/projects");
      const data = [{"id":"f0dc4b06-063a-4ed7-a712-463b418ae436","slug":"starter","name":"Starter","is_starter":true}];
      setProjects(data);
    };
    fetchProjects();
  }, []);
```

then It is working.

just wondering why the hook just failed to work

Answer (score 0):

`useProjects` returns a promise, not an array.

To facilitate async state, typically your custom hook would maintain that state internally and update it when your `fetch()` request resolves.

It's also a good idea to track *loading* and *error* states too.

```ts
// I'm just guessing the `Project` type

const fetchProjects = async (): Promise<Project[]> => {
  const res = await fetch("/api/projects");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  return res.json();
};

export default async function useProjects() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<Project[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  // fetch projects on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchProjects()
      .then(setProjects)
      .catch(setError)
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  // return the state
  return { projects, loading, error };
}
```

Then in your components, consume the hook

```ts
const { projects, loading, error } = useProjects();
```

You can use the `error` and `loading` states to decide what to render and when.

---

Libraries like [Tanstack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest) do all this and much more a lot better. I'd recommend trying them out.